# Visual Studio is not stopping on breakpoints after I installed Intel Parallel Studio 

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, debugging

I installed Intel Parallel Studio v1.0, and now Visual Studio 2008 is not stopping on breakpoints. I can set them, but it skips right over them, and never breaks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested Solution: Intel Parallel Studio had automatically turned off “Generate Debugging Info”. Switched it on again in "Configuration..Linker..Debugging..Generate Debug Info", and everything worked fine again.